# 'at' command running with increased niceness

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, scripting

When executing a script as a non-root user using `at` command, it runs it with increased niceness. 
I read in the manual that it differs when using uppercase letter queues, but even with explicit `-q a` (which is also default), it still doesn't do the trick.

Here is a simple example:

- scheduled:

```bsh
➔ at -q a 18:02
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> /bin/bash ~/sleep_and_count.sh 60 > ~/sleep_at_test.log
at> <EOT>
job 10 at Thu Jan  2 18:02:00 2020
```

- executed in parallel:

```bsh
➔ /bin/bash ~/sleep_and_count.sh 60 > ~/sleep_at_test1.log
```

List of processes including niceness (the one with NI=2 is coming from `at`:

```bsh
  PID  NI CMD
11839   2 sh
11840   2 /bin/bash /home/tcigler/sleep_and_count.sh 60
12441   0 /bin/bash /home/tcigler/sleep_and_count.sh 60
12459   2 sleep 1
12469   0 sleep 1
```

The goal is to schedule one-time application restart = execute script once at specific time within 24h period in future, but **using non-root technical user**. Increased niceness is a problem, because the application after restart is running slow. Otherwise the `at` command would be working fine.

How to achieve that?

Comment: AFAICT, in the Debian/Ubuntu distribution of `at`, the call to `nice` can't be avoided unless you edit the source code for the at daemon atd.c and recompile it.

Comment: Is there some alternative to `at` than?

Comment: Most systems allow you to set up a personal `crontab`. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html . The file format isn't as straightforward as the date format that `at` uses, because cron is designed for programs to run periodically, but it's completely documented in the man pages.

Comment: Thanks. Cron I already use, but when I want to make it one-time action, I need to call `crontab -r` as the last command. It now collides with another job which should be scheduled really periodically.

Comment: It's easy to make a cron job run once. Set up minute, hour, day, month, and * in crontab, which will make it run once a year, and then have it run a shell script like `if ! [ -f /path/to/ok-to-run ] then exit; ...; rm /path/to/ok-to-run` so that it'll only run when you want it to.